# User friendly SQL query program?

Tags: sql

I doubt this could exist, but crazier things do. Is there a program or place where I could enter in just the tables/columns, and some criteria options and it will generate a working SQL query code for me?

I know there are programs that will make the code look all nice, but I mean truly generate the code/joins/FROMS/etc.

Comment: Doubt it. Go learn SQL instead. It's fun!

Comment: SQL Studio/Access Query Builder

Comment: There are libraries that do this in application code.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using the views section (if you are using sql server) to help you write select statements.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, SQL Server Management Studio's query designer. Here's a quick guide to get you started: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1086/sql-server-2005-management-studio-query-designer/

Comment: is www.sqlfiddle.com sort of what you're looking for?

Comment: Very many such tools have been created over the years, almost ever since the relational model was first described in 1969.  QBE (Query-By-Example) was one of the early ones, for example.  The problem with any such tool is whether it lets you deal with the complexity of the queries you need to write.  Typically, they'll handle the easy ones that you could write without too much thinking, but they won't handle the hard ones which is when you really need the help (not least because describing what you need is what makes the hard ones hard).

Comment: Thats about what I expected as far as options. I was really just putting my hopes into being able to input the tables I have and the columns I want to show up. I think another problemw with what i am using is, and i've never dealt with any database on its own, my system gives me an interface to enter the code instead of a big text box to enter all the code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually with `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio` you have tools for everything.
You just need to learn the basics, but almost everything can be done with pre-made code for you.

- You can create a table by just `Right-Clicking` on a database and select Create Table. From there you just have to fill the column names and the rows.
- You can fill you rows with something similar without using the `T-SQL` language directly.
- There are too many tools for me to list them all here but it is really User-Friendly.

I do recommend you go and [learn SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365303.aspx). It is really easy to learn the basics and so useful.

If you really want a software that generates the code for you you can google SQL Genetator.

I found [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asqlg/). Although I don't recommend using a code generator.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone already commented, SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is your tool to go. But I guess you are asking for something that maybe requires a little bit less knowledge of the underlying tSQL language.

A sample could be [MS SQL Code Factory](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/mssql/codefactory/) I once recommended to some advanced user of a system I used to work and for him it was enough to do simple and some mid-adavanced queries.

But definitely you should aim to learn tSQL and then apply your knowledge together with a tool like SSMS to create all the queries you need, there is "almost" no limit on what you can achieve, and it is fun too as @Polynomial stated

Comment: The problem is my job doesn't (usually require) knowledge of coding and sql it just so happens that the program we use has the feature that if you know sql you can benefit from it. I don't know if investing so much time into learning it would be worth the time vs the times I will actually need it. Thanks for all the help though I will look into it.